# I am looking for a function in an $L^p$ space

Tags: integration

Does it exists a positive function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that
$\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^N}f(x)>0$?

Comment: Is this not bothering you anymore?

Answer (score 0):

No, since $$\int_{\mathbb{R^N}} f^2 \geq \inf \{f(x^2)\} \cdot |\mathbb{R^N}|=\infty$$ if $\inf > 0$